# How to Show/Hide nested array element/component after mapping outer array with useState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Initial objective:

- I have 4 components, when clicking on one of the components, the other three components disappear to only show the one that is clicked. Clicking on the component again toggles all the components to display again.
- My goal is to add an info/description object to each of the components in the array so that when a component is toggled, the other components still disappear but now a description shows up in accordance with the toggled component.
- My thought process is to set a visibility flag to the description element, set it to false, and toggling a specific component will change the flag to true and have the description appear.
  Here is my current take on it:

```
const array = [
    { id: 1, component: <Comp1/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: [{ id: 5, component: <div>info1</div>, isVisibleInfo: false }] },

    { id: 2, component: <Comp2/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: [{ id: 6, component: <div>info2</div>, isVisibleInfo: false }] },

    { id: 3, component: <Comp3/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: [{ id: 7, component: <div>info3</div>, isVisibleInfo: false }] },

    { id: 4, component: <Comp4/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: [{ id: 8, component: <div>info4</div>, isVisibleInfo: false }] }
  ];

  
  export const Test = () => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState(array);
  
    const handleClick = (number) => {
      const triggeredItems = items.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== number) {
          item.isVisible = !item.isVisible;
        }
  
        return item;
      });
  
      setItems(triggeredItems);
    };

    const handleClickInner = (number) => {
      const triggeredItemsInner = items.info.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== number) {
          item.isVisibleInfo = !item.isVisibleInfo;
        }
  
        return item;
      });
  
      setItems(triggeredItemsInner);
    };

  
    return (
      <div className="mt-1 pt-1 pb-3 px-3">
        <div className="row text-center d-flex my-1">
        {items.map(({ id, component, isVisible, info }) => (
          <div
            key={id}
            className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 justify-content-center"
            onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
            hidden={!isVisible}
          >
            { component }

            {info.map(({ id, component, isVisibleInfo }) => (
            <div
              key={id}
              className="col-lg-9 col-md-6 mb-4 justify-content-center"
              onClick={() => { handleClickInner(id)}}
              hidden={isVisibleInfo}
            >
              { component }
              
            </div>
          ))}
          </div>
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  export default Test;
```

At the moment, I am getting this output TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in the 'handleClickInner function because I believe map cannot map a nested array, but in general I am not sure if creating this second function is the right approach even.

Still learning a lot about React and it's methods!

Any thoughts or help would appreciated!

Comment: `items` is not an object, `items` is an *array* of objects. So `items.info` is undefined. You'd need to access a specific object in order to make over its info array, e.g. `items[0].info.map`

Comment: @Jayce444 Ok I see, thanks for the info. I'm not sure if creating a second function to map through like I have right now is the right way to achieve what I am looking to accomplish, it was my initial thought process.

Comment: I'd do exactly what you're thinking... sounds reacty to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to add an info/description object to each of the components
> in the array so that when a component is toggled, the other components
> still disappear but now a description shows up in accordance with the
> toggled component.

You dont really mean disappear do you? sounds more like you want to conditionally render the component.

**UPDATED**

I misunderstood your intentions! Now they disappear.

```js
// hooks
const {useState} = React;

function Comp1(){
  return <div><p>Component 1</p></div>
}
function Comp2(){
  return <div><p>Component 2</p></div>
}
function Comp3(){
  return <div><p>Component 3</p></div>
}
function Comp4(){
  return <div><p>Component 4</p></div>
}

const array = [
    { id: 1, component: <Comp1/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: { id: 5, component: <div>info1</div>, isVisibleInfo: false } },

    { id: 2, component: <Comp2/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: { id: 6, component: <div>info2</div>, isVisibleInfo: false } },

    { id: 3, component: <Comp3/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: { id: 7, component: <div>info3</div>, isVisibleInfo: false } },

    { id: 4, component: <Comp4/>, isVisible: true, 
      info: { id: 8, component: <div>info4</div>, isVisibleInfo: false } }
  ];

const Test = () => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState(array);
  
    const handleClick = (number) => {
      
      const triggeredItems = items.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== number) {
          item.isVisible = !item.isVisible;
        }
        item.info.isVisibleInfo =! item.info.isVisibleInfo
  
        return item;
      });
  
      setItems(triggeredItems);
    };

  
    return (
      <div className="mt-1 pt-1 pb-3 px-3">
        <div className="row text-center d-flex my-1">
        {items.map(({ id, component, isVisible, info }) => (
          isVisible ? 
          <div
            key={id}
            className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 justify-content-center"
            onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
            hidden={!isVisible}
          >
            { component }
          {info.isVisibleInfo ? 
          <div
              key={info.id}
              className="col-lg-9 col-md-6 mb-4 justify-content-center"
            >
              { info.component }
              
            </div>
            : null}
          </div>
          : null
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };


function App(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, conditionally render is the correct terminology I believe. I tested your code out and the output I am getting are the 3 div Info tags that are not in correspondence to the component that is clicked on haha. For example, if I click <comp1/> then the output is 'info2, info3, info4'. Instead of just 'info1'. Is that an issue with my handleClick function?

Comment: No, I thought that was your goal ^_^. I'll update the code.

Comment: Just what I needed! Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to have the info object be in its own div tag outside the div tag of Comp1 for example?

Comment: A component can only render one div `<div><p>hi</p><p>there</p></div>` is fine but not `<div>1</div><div>2</div>`

Comment: That makes sense. I just thought if I wrapped `<div>1</div><div>2<div/>` with an outer div such that it looks as: `<div> <div>1</div><div>2<div/> </div>`. Then my assumption is `<div>1</div>` and `<div>2</div>` would act as their own elements inside the outer tag. However, when I test this, `<div>2</div>` still acts as a child element to `<div>1</div>` it seems. Is this just how it is? Just confused by it.

Comment: You can do that. Think of it like this; a component has to have a container div. So you can do `<div className='container'><div>inner 1</div><div>inner2</div></div>`